# Are collections of inner aggregates valid?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Lets say I have an AggregateRoot called Folder with a collection of sub-folders like this:

```
class Folder : AggregateRoot
{
  string Name { get; }
  ICollection<Folder> Folders { get; }
}
```

The inner collection here is really just a list of aggregate-ids to other Folder-aggregates which is resolved lazily when enumerated.

Is this construct valid in domain modeling where aggregates not only references other aggregates but also defines its Folders-property as a collection of other Folder-aggregates?

Why? The example above may not be particularly good but my goal is mainly to have a natural way of working with aggregate collections and hide the fact that agg-references are resolved through a repository under the surface. I want to work with aggregates as easily as with entity-collections.

My thinking here is also that the sub-folders in some way are owned by the parent-aggregate, that the collection really is a way of representing a place where the aggregates are stored even if it's not really true as they are stored more generally through a repository.

The example with the recursiveness was not really important. The focus is on the fact that a aggregate "seem" to own other aggregates. And when making a change in two folders it would only be possible to save them one by one of course but that should be ok. I would also have to include some rule that folders only can be created in place and not added manually so that they could turn up in more than one agg-collection.

Answer (score 0):

Child Structures are valid use cases in Domain Modeling, and one often encountered in recursive concepts like Groups, Tags, etc. just like in your example of Folders. And I like dealing with them as pure collection objects in the domain layer, with no hint of persistence logic whatsoever. When writing such domain logic, I like to imagine that I am dealing with objects as if they will be perpetually preserved on the RAM .

I will consider your recursive example for my explanation, but the same concept applies to any "collection" of child objects, not just recursive relationships.

Below is a sample implementation in pseudocode, annotated with comments. I apologize in advance that the code is closer to Python in structure. I wanted to convey the idea accurately, and not worry about how to represent it in C#, in which I am not well versed. Please ask questions about the code if something is not clear.

**Notes on the pseudocode:**

1. In the domain layer, you deal with collections simply as if its another list/collection, without having to worry about underlying persistence complexities.
2. `FolderService` is an `ApplicationService` that is typically invoked by the API. This service is responsible for assembling the infrastructure services, interacting with the domain layer, and eventual persistence.
3. `FolderTable` is an imaginary database representation of the `Folder` object. `FolderRepository` along knows about this class and its implementation details
4. The complexities of saving and retrieving the Folder object from DB would be present only in the `FolderRepository` class.
5. The `load_by_name` repository method eagerly loads and populates all subfolders into the parent folder. We can convert this to be lazily loaded, only on access, and never load it unless we are traversing (can even be paginated, based on requirements, especially if there is no specific limit on the no. of subfolders)

```
class Folder(AggregateRoot):
    name: str
    folders: List[Folder]

    @classmethod
    def construct_from_args(cls, params):
        # This is a factory method
        return Folder(**params)

    def add_sub_folder(self, new_folder: Folder) -> None:
        self.folders.append(new_folder)

    def remove_sub_folder(self, existing_folder: Folder) -> None:
        # Dummy implementation. Actual implementation will be more involved
        for folder in self.folders:
            if folder.name == existing_folder.name:
                self.folders.remove(existing_folder)


class FolderService(ApplicationService):

    def add_sub_folder(parent_folder_name: str, new_folder_params: dict) -> None:
        folder_repo = _system.get_folder_repository()
        parent_folder = folder_repo.load_by_name(parent_folder_name)

        new_sub_folder = Folder.construct_from_args(new_folder_params)
        parent_folder.add_sub_folder(new_sub_folder)

        folder_repo.save(parent_folder)


class FolderTable(DBObject):
    # A DB representation of the folder domain object
    #   `parent_id` will be empty for the root folder
    name: str
    parent_id: integer


class FolderRepository(Repository):
    # Constructor for Repository
    #   that has `connection`s to the database, for later use

    # FolderRepository works exclusively with `FolderTable` class

    def load_by_name(self, folder_name: str) -> Folder:
        # Load a folder, including its subfolders, from database
        persisted_folder = self.connection.find(name=folder_name)

        parent_identifier = persisted_folder.id
        sub_folders = self.connection.find(parent_identifier)
        for sub_folder in sub_folders:
            persisted_folder.folders.append(sub_folder)

        return persisted_folder

    def save(self, folder: Folder) -> None:
        persisted_folder = self.connection.find(name=folder.name)
        parent_identifier = persisted_folder.id

        # Gather the persisted list of folders from database
        persisted_sub_folders = self.connection.find(parent_identifier)

        for sub_folder in folder.folders:
            # The heart of the persistence logic, with three conditions:

            # If the subfolder is already persisted,
            #   Do Nothing

            # If there is a persisted subfolder that is no longer a part of folders,
            #   Remove it

            # If the subfolder is not among those already persisted,
            #   Add it
```

If you see holes in this implementation or my thought-process, please do point them out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, but the question was not so much about how to implement it but more about the modeling choice from a DDD perspective and especially if it's a common approach or if it's bad practice or just strange and wrong? The thing I'm concerned with is that it may look as if the inner aggregates are really part of the parent aggregate as with normal internal entities and that it may be confusing for "consumers" or really bad in some way I have not foreseen yet.

Comment: Understood. This is an approach that I have used repeatedly for recursive relationships and child objects. Never felt that it causes a problem in terms of understanding or modeling. It's intuitive once built.

Answer (score 0):

When an aggregate contains another one should avoid direct references as there is usually some unwanted pain that follows.

Any *lazy-loading* would indicate that you could redesign things a bit as you should avoid that also.

The most common pattern is to either have only a list of ids or a list of values objects.  The latter appears to be more appropriate in your case.  You could then always have a fully loaded AR with all the relevant folders.  In order to *navigate* you would need to retrieve the relevant folder.

This particular example has some peculiarities since it represents a hierarchy but you'd have to deal with those on a case-by-base bases.

In short: having any aggregate reference another, whether it be through a collection or otherwise, is ill-advised.